# How to determine image size for skimage.view_as_windows function?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-image, resize-image

Currently, I am working with matrix M * N and I want to divide image into several parts with `skimage.view_as_windows` with `window_shape=(p,p)` and `step=s`. But unfortunately, sometimes the input shape is inappropriate to be an input to that function.

example: if my input image is (5,5) but my window_shape is (4,4) with step = 2 then I have to resize my to (6,6) because the function will throw an error if the input is in its original size.

if the window_shape is (3,3) and step = 2 then image size (5, 5) is fine

Current state: For window_shape(m, m) and step = m

```
# check height and width
height, width, depth = img.shape

_h = math.ceil(height / patch) * patch
_w = math.ceil(width / patch) * patch
img.resize((_h, _w)
```

How can I calculate the desired image size to be able to resize the image for different step?

Thanks!

Comment: `numpy.view_as_windows` is not a function that seems to exist.

Comment: He probably meant [skimage's](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows). But even then it's totally unclear what is being asked.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *sometimes the input shape is inappropriate*. Maybe provide examples of appropriate and inappropriate shapes?

Comment: @sascha probably, but that one has no `stride` argument.

Comment: @sascha ah yeah you're right! sorry I put the wrong lib.

Comment: @ellamunde So `image_size - window_shape` must be multiple of `step` to be valid.

Comment: @kazemakase how about the step? what if I change the step? how's the calculation?

Comment: @ellamunde *... multiple of `step` (or stride)*. Do you realize that there are many possible image sizes? E.g. shape (4, 4) and step 2 would work for images of size (4, 4), (6, 6), (8, 8), (10, 10), ... How would you resolve that ambiguity?

Comment: @kazemakase yes, I notice it that's why I ask this question :D if I don't really care about the stride, I can just use the nearest multiplication of the window_shape. But I want to use another step, so that's why I ask how to calculate the desired image

Comment: 1) if you realized you were referencing the wrong package, you should probably have changed your tags (I did it for you now).  2) without some idea of what the "desired image size" means, theres no way we (or the `skimage` folks) will be able to help you.  Please show your current code.

Comment: @DanielF thanks for your input